# Declaring an empty element before insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, insertadjacenthtml

Hi I have a simple question, do I need to specify `lblWelcomeUserMessage.innerHTML = ""; ( see below in code )` in the following function `before insertAdjacentHTML` on it ? It actually works as it is without declaring it, but I want to know what is the `optimal approach` ?

```
// Dynamic HTML / user interface for ALL users
  function showWelcomeMessage() {

      //lblWelcomeUserMessage.innerHTML = "";

      var sWelcomeUserMessage = '<h3>' + 'Welcome:' + '  ' + sessionStorage.getItem( 'name' ) + 
      '  ' +  sessionStorage.getItem( 'lastname' ) + '  ' + sessionStorage.getItem( 'role' ) + ' </h3>';
      var iUserImage = '<img src=" ' + sessionStorage.getItem( 'image' ) + ' " width="50px">';
      lblWelcomeUserMessage.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', sWelcomeUserMessage + iUserImage );
  }
```

Comment: An "optimal  approach" depends on what you want to emphasize, performance, security, less code ... Security-wise the approach would be to create the H3 element and the image, and then populate the header using `textContent`, and setting the properties of the image by ... well ... properties, or attributes. Finally append these elements to the desired element. This is probably also the most performant approach. Less code approach would use a single `innerHTML` only, which will override the previous content without emptying it beforehand.

Comment: really nice explanation. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

> If you are calling `showWelcomeMessage` function more than once then
>   you need to set it to empty `lblWelcomeUserMessage.innerHTML = ""`
>
> ```
>        function showWelcomeMessage() {
>
>   lblWelcomeUserMessage.innerHTML = "";
>
>    var sWelcomeUserMessage = '<h3>' + 'Welcome:' + '  ' + sessionStorage.getItem( 'name' ) + 
>   '  ' +  sessionStorage.getItem( 'lastname' ) + '  ' + sessionStorage.getItem( 'role' ) + ' </h3>';
>   var iUserImage = '<img src=" ' + sessionStorage.getItem( 'image' ) + ' " width="50px">';
>   lblWelcomeUserMessage.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', sWelcomeUserMessage + iUserImage );
>   }
>
>    setInterval(showWelcomeMessage,4000);
> ```

OR

> Otherwise you can remove `lblWelcomeUserMessage.innerHTML = "";` from
>   above code

Answer (score 1):

`insertAdjacentHTML` [inserts some HTML around a node](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) (`lblWelcomeUserMessage`, which you should have get before with something like `lblWelcomeUserMessage = document.getElementById('welcome_tag')`).

Setting it's inner content to an empty string is not really necessary, unless you want to clear it. It's rather a design issue than a programmatic one.

Answer (score 0):

**Optimal approach for what?**

By the way based on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

> insertAdjacentHTML() parses the specified text as HTML or XML and
>   inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.
>   It does not reparse the element it is being used on and thus it does
>   not corrupt the existing elements inside that element. This avoids the
>   extra step of serialization, making it much faster than direct
>   innerHTML manipulation.

So it's basically depends on your needs. If you want to replace previous message you just add the `lblWelcomeUserMessage.innerHTML = "";` , if you want to show all previous message just comment that code.